# How can I swap two bits of integer in Java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, swap

Is there a built in function in Java that I could use to swap two bits?

For example:

_ _ _ _ 1 _ _ 0  bit 3 swapped with bit 0 and becomes   _ _ _ _ 0 _ _ 1

I know it can be done using a long procedure of bit-wise operation, but I want to avoid doing so.

Comment: How long do you want it to not be? I don't think there's a built-in that specifically swaps bits.

Comment: not  exists such a function

Comment: "Long procedure of bit-wise operation" is the way to go, though it probably won't be that long.

Comment: Java integer is **not 1 byte** like you show. Did you by any chance mean `byte?`

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm guessing OP simplified it so as not to need to write 30 blank spaces.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard well you have to do AND operation and bring each bit in others corresponding location and then you can swap them by doing another bit-wise operation, i thought there might be some packages/libraries to this

Comment: @PM77-1 8 bits i showed is for simplicity but i wana do this for integers(32bits)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm making it in details, but you can join it into single line

```
 int temp1 = (i & 0x1) << 3; //extract lowest bit #1 and place at pos# 4
 int temp2 = (i & 0x8) >> 3; //extract bit #4 and place at pos #1
 i = (i & temp1) | (i & ~temp1); //now pos #4 is ready     
 i = (i & temp2) | (i & ~temp2); //now pos #1 is ready
```

Answer (score 13):

You can also try this way

```
//positions are indexed from 0 and in order ...[4][3][2][1][0]
//so changing 3 and 0 will make             ...[4][0][2][1][3]
public static int swapBits(int n, int pos1, int pos2) {

    int bit1 = (n >> pos1) & 1;// bit at pos1
    int bit2 = (n >> pos2) & 1;// bit at pos2

    if (bit1 == bit2) // no need to swap since we change 1 with 1 or 0 with 0
        return n;     // so we can return original value

    // Since we are here it means that we need to change 1->0 and 0->1.
    // To do this we can use XOR (^).
    // Lets create mask like 000001001 with 1 at positions which need "reversing"
    int mask = (1 << pos1) | (1 << pos2);
    
    return n ^ mask;// TA-DAH!!!
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's an alternative way, called a delta-swap.

```
int t = (i ^ (i >> 3)) & 1;
return i ^ t ^ (t << 3);
```

Or more generally:

```
static int swap(int x, int i, int j)
{
    // precondition: i > j
    int d = i - j;
    int y = (x ^ (x >> d)) & (1 << j);
    return x ^ y ^ (y << d);
}
```